# OpenCV Mat constructor with Rect parameter

Tags: opencv

I am trying to get a sub Mat from a Mat by doing something like

```
    Mat subImage = Image(rect);
```

When I do that, even though rect is within the Image boundaries, I get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat

Why does `roi.x + roi.width` need to be less than/equal to `m.cols` (similarly for `roi.y`, `roi.height`, and `m.rows`)? I would think that it would be fine as long as `roi.x` and `roi.y` are within `m` and `roi.width <= m.cols` and `roi.height <= m.rows`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your main Image is 100x100.  The starting point of your roi is `roi.x`, and let's say it's at 30.  This leaves you 70 from the edge of the image, so your `roi.width` can be anything up to 70 without going out of bounds, hence the requirement for `roi.x + roi.width < m.cols`.  If you have `roi.width == 80` for example, that's less than `m.cols`, but you're still out of bounds.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!  I got confused because the main image was also a subimage, and I was still using the original image's starting point relative to the roi rather than the new main image's starting point.